# google maps doesn't display on app form google play?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, google-play-services

when I test the app on a real device, google maps works fine, but when downloading the same app from google play, this is what I got :
[image]

the app doesn't crash but I can't see any thing, what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its to do with your API key coming from the google API console.

Make sure you use the SHA1 key coming from your key file

When you sign your APK with the given key file.  In the end of signing, there is a SHA1 key shown before you click create signed APK.  use that SHA1 in your google API console

Comment: yes , sha1 in the preferences -> android - > build ! that is right?

Comment: when you export your APK with a key. In the end of process, you will see a SHA1 there, use that 1